# Html table only last row instead of all rows is inserting in mysql database

Tags: php, html

I am implementing clothing shopping website. I am having a problem when I place order only last row item from the shopping cart HTML table is inserted into the database and not all rows. I want that when I click on place order button all rows values should be inserted in the database. so that customers all selected items in the shopping cart should be placed for order.
Here is the code,

```
    <table align="center"  >
        <thead>
          <tr >
            <th>Product</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>QTY</th>
            <th>SubTotal</th>

          </tr>
        </thead>

        <?php 
                if (!empty($_SESSION["shopping_cart"])) 
                {
                    $total=0;
                    foreach ($_SESSION["shopping_cart"] as $keys => $values) {

        ?>

        <tr>
          <td>
          <p>Product Code:<?php echo $values["item_id"]; ?> <br/>
          <?php echo $values["item_gender"]; ?><br/>
    <?php echo $values["item_description"]; ?> </p></td>

          <td>PKR
<input type="number" name="price1" id="price1" value="<?php echo $values["item_price"];?>" readonly ></td>

          <td><input type="number"  name="qty[<?php echo $values["item_id"]; ?>]" id="qty" value="<?php echo $values["item_quantity"];?>"></td>

          <input type="hidden" name="qty" value="<?php echo $values["item_quantity"];?>"  >

          <td >PKR<input type="number" name="total" id="total" value="<?php echo ($values["item_quantity"] * $values["item_price"]) ?>"readonly></td>


        </tr>

        <?php
                       $total=$total+($values['item_quantity']*$values["item_price"]);  
                     /*  $total=$total+$values["item_price"]; */
       }
            } ?>
      </table> <br/><br/>

<button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Place Order</button>

here is php code,
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
            {



                        $product_code = $_POST['ID'];

                        $price = $_POST['grandtotal'];

                        $quantity = $_POST['qty'];

                        $description = $_POST['description'];


                          $email=$_SESSION["email"];



                                $con=mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
                        mysql_select_db("login",$con);



              $qry="INSERT INTO order ( order_description , product_code,  order_quantity, order_price, customer_name, email, customer_id) VALUES ('$description', '$product_code',  '$quantity', '$price', (SELECT name from users where email='$email'), '$email', (SELECT user_id from users where email='$email') ) ";

                    $result=mysql_query($qry,$con);
                    if($result)

                    {
      echo '<script>alert("Your order has been placed")</script>';
                    echo '<script>window.location="portfolionew.php"</script>';
  } else {
    die("Error While Adding Stock ! Please Try Again .");
  }
       }
```

Comment: please remove the javascript tag, just confuses people there is no js in your code, nor the problem you are facing is js related. Thanks

Comment: @N. Ivanov thanks i removed it

Comment: Honestly - having only the last row inserted is the least of your problems; you're using an obsolete database connector with code that's wide open to SQL injection attacks... and what's with the nested queries where an `INNER JOIN` would be better? I'd suggest finding an up-to-date tutorial and starting again.

Comment: **Don't** use the **deprecated and insecure** _mysql_*-functions. They have been deprecated since PHP 5.5 (in 2013) and were completely removed in PHP 7 (in 2015). Use MySQLi or PDO instead. 2. You are **wide open to** [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating your queries, which can be used if you use the above mentioned MySQLi or PDO.

Comment: The form doesn't make sense either - you're echoing out inputs in a loop yet have `<input type="number" name="price1"` since the name doesn't change PHP will only pick up the value from the last iteration, same with `name="total"` ... then you've got both `name="qty"` and `name="qty[]"`

Answer (score -1):

```
    <table align="center">
    <thead>
      <tr >
        <th>Product</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th>QTY</th>
        <th>SubTotal</th>

      </tr>
    </thead>

    <?php 
            if (!empty($_SESSION["shopping_cart"])) 
            {
                $total=0;
                $i = 1;
                foreach ($_SESSION["shopping_cart"] as $keys => $values) {

    ?>

    <tr>
      <td style=" text-align: left;" >
      <p style="margin-top: -120px; margin-left: 150px;">Product Code:<?php echo $values["item_id"]; ?> <br/>
      <?php echo $values["item_gender"]; ?><br/>
<?php echo $values["item_description"]; ?> </p></td>

      <td style="text-align: left; width: 80px;">PKR<br/>
<input style="width: 70px;" type="number" name="price<?= $i; ?>" id="price<?= $i; ?>" value="<?php echo $values["item_price"];?>" readonly ></td>

      <td><input type="number"  name="qty_<?= $i; ?>" id="qty_<?= $i; ?>" value="<?php echo $values["item_quantity"];?>"></td>

      <td style="text-align: left; width: 80px;">&nbsp;&nbsp;<b>PKR</b>
  <br/>&nbsp;<input style="width: 70px; "  type="number" name="total" id="total" value="<?php echo ($values["item_quantity"] * $values["item_price"]) ?>"readonly></td>


    </tr>

    <?php
                   $total=$total+($values['item_quantity']*$values["item_price"]);  
                   $i++;
                 /*  $total=$total+$values["item_price"]; */
   }
        } ?>
    <input hidden="iTotalProducts" value="<?php echo $i; ?>" name="product_count">
  </table> <br/><br/>

 <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Place Order</button>

     //here is php code,
         if (isset($_POST['submit']))
        {




                    $product_code = $_POST['ID'];

                    $price = $_POST['grandtotal'];

                    $quantity = $_POST['qty'];

                    $description = $_POST['description'];


                      $email=$_SESSION["email"];



                            $con=mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
                    mysql_select_db("login",$con);

                    $cnt = $_POST["iTotalProducts"];

                    for($i = 1; $i <= $cnt; $i++) {
                       // here you can write your insert code
                    }



                if($result)

                {
  echo '<script>alert("Your order has been placed")</script>';
                echo '<script>window.location="portfolionew.php"</script>';
} else {
   die("Error While Adding Stock ! Please Try Again .");
  }
   } `enter code here`
```